# Print datatable and Chart using Typescript

Tags: javascript, highcharts, datatable

I am working with `HighChart` and one feature what I need to add its a `datatable` together with the `chart`.

I am following the next [example](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/z9zXM/) and I am getting some problem with the key `This`.

Basically when I try make a simple assignment from this to another variable I got a wrong value for my variable.

I can't reproduce it in jsfiddle so I put the code and one image here

```
chart: {
  events: {
  load: () => {
  debugger;
  var obj = this;
  alert("loaded"); //in this point obj=document what is wrong
}
}
}
```

[image: As you see obj should be equals= HighCharts.Chart]

Comment: `this` is context related, so it will give different values depending on where you are in the code.

Comment: thats right, but this has the same value in all load() method. the problem is  with the assignment of the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
load: function () {
```

instead of:

```
load: () => {
```

this will then refer to the chart instead of the document. Refer to this fiddle that is from the Highcharts documentation:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/events-load/